# Flux - suspend all listeners and enable them

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am using react and [flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/) in my application. On componentWillMount we add listeners and on componentWillUnmount we remove the listeners.

I have come across a scenario where I need to suspend/disable all the active listeners and after performing some changes, I need to enable all the listeners. Does Flux provide something out of the box to get the desired result.

Comment: Which framework of flux are you using (redux, reflux, ..)?

Comment: @DamienLeroux: I am using regular flux from facebook. I update link in the question.